# services throwing error in the controller as function not defined

Tags: angularjs

```
amcApp.service('utilService', function ($http, $q,$rootScope) {
    var getSupportTypes = function () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get($rootScope.BaseUrl+'vendor/supportTypes')
            .then(function daoSuccess(response) {
                console.log("Getting Sub Customer Service call success ", response);
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function daoError(reason) {
                console.log("Getting SubC data service call error", reason);
                deferred.reject(reason);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return{
        getSupportTypes : getSupportTypes,       
    };
});
```

Above is the service I defined.

Below is the controller I defined.

```
amcApp.controller('contractForm', ['$scope', '$http','$rootScope','$filter', '$uibModal', '$state', 'testService','utilService','contractService',
 function ($scope, $http,$rootScope, $filter,$uibModal, testService,utilService,contractService) {
          //Service of getting the Support Types.
        utilService.getSupportTypes().then(function(response){
                        $scope.supportTypes = response.data.UtilDataType;
        });
}]);
```

This is the error I'm getting:
[image]

Can I get any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the dependencies what you inject into the controller, you have an extra $state in the array which has not been passed to the function. I would suggest to remove as the following:

```js
amcApp.controller('contractForm', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$filter', '$uibModal', 'testService','utilService','contractService',
 function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $filter, $uibModal, testService, utilService, contractService) {
   //Service of getting the Support Types.
   utilService.getSupportTypes().then(function (response){
      $scope.supportTypes = response.data.UtilDataType;
   });
}]);
```

On the other hand I would simply remove all the not used services, I assume this is working also fine:

```js
amcApp.controller('contractForm', ['$scope', 'utilService', function ($scope, utilService) {
   //Service of getting the Support Types.
   utilService.getSupportTypes().then(function (response) {
      $scope.supportTypes = response.data.UtilDataType;
   });
}]);
```

Just a suggestion - if you keep your code clean it is much easier to figure out the root cause of any issues.